# Dynamically updating numbers based on date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am looking for a formula/way to dynamically update a list of stores that is receiving a product, based on if a date has passed. EX: xxx out of 4000 stores have received this product as of a now (date changes every day)

I believe this would be a countifs formula, but im not sure exactly how to write it out.

=countifs(date(now)>"cell with date")

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(A:A,"<=" & NOW())`?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that the column with dates is column D.

```
=COUNTIF(D:D, "<=" & TODAY())
```

The formula will help you get a list of stores updated.